# Acumatica GI Inventory Turnover

Tags: sql, report, acumatica, join

I have created a GI for Inventory Turnover which shows

Inventory ID  |  Inventory Desc  |  Purchase Qty  |  Shipped Qty

I am having trouble joining the Purchase side with the Shipments, because the values are not shown for Shipped Qty in the GI

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like it might be tricky using those 2 tables (poline & soline/solinesplit) together. Have you looked into using INTran? all po and so transactions should funnel to INTran and you can show all of the ins and outs. I am assuming you want to show aggregate information tho? maybe provide some example on how the data should look. is it 1 row per item. or detail such as all po and shipped transactions (each line is a shipment or po receipt)

Comment: I want to display 1 row per item. Included the screenshot in the question above. Couldn't find Shipped qty and Purchase qty in INTran

Comment: You would then need a query that is going to aggregate the values for you. The generic inquiry is not going to do this. Short of writing some type of PXProjection DAC for use in the generic inquiry, a report might be your easiest option otherwise. The way you have it you are getting detail (multiple rows per same item)

Comment: Report in Report Designer? or Financial Reports...because in Report Designer will have to join the tables again.

Comment: report designer. you could roll up the totals in a group for quick thinking. And yes you will have to join the tables but i think if you use INTran you do not need to join the tables that end up in INTran anyhow.

Comment: The INTran table doesn't have Purchase Qty, We will get the purchase qty from the PO tables only I guess. So will have to find a way to Join PO with SO